# Shortcut icon doesn't display icon, task manager displays weird version of it C#

Tags: c#, icons, setup-wizard

I made an ico file. I made it my default icon for application, but on task manager it changes icon. It makes background white.

When i expand on task manager it shows correct icon on form1. Also it shows correct icon for normal exe. But shortcut ( created with setup wizard ) has no icon at all.

I tried to change to release but nothing changed, i have no idea why.

Here are some screenshots:

- [Add icon Part to shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xoo2.png) I choose the exe file. Also tried to
  choose ico file with in still same result
- [Task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y22y7.png)
- [Shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJS3P.png) Which has no icon at all?
- [Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIISQ.png)

Comment: Can you try to right click your project -> Properties -> Application Tab (1st Tab)  and select your item there

Comment: I already added an icon there.

Answer (score 0):

how did you create this icon?

it could be a problem of inadequate processing during the saving.

try working on a PNG file and then convert it to an icon, using a tool like this [pngtoico](http://convertico.com/)

Comment: I created at illustrator as PNG file then converted on a site like you said. So this is not the case...